# OnClickListener of full itemView and OnClickListeners for views within it

Tags: android

I have a Layout within an ImageView and a textview. I would like to add a onClickListner for each view and the full itemview. I am using a PagerAdapter. In the instantiateItem Method I call this:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(context, ProfileActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra(StaticVariables.INTENT_USERID, v.getId());


                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {


                        ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                                makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity, imageView, imageView.getTransitionName());
                        ActivityCompat.startActivity(activity, i, options.toBundle());
                    } else {
                        activity.startActivity(i);
                        activity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.gehnachlinks, R.anim.stay);
                    }
                }
            });
```

and textView:

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mLayout.setPanelState(SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.EXPANDED);
                }
            });
```

and now I would like to add a OnLongClickListner to the full itemView. I tried to implement a OnLongClickListner to the full Adapter and add this with "itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);" but it didn't worked. I guess it doesn't work because the ClickListeners of the views "cut" the onlongclick of the full item.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:descendFocusability="blocked"` in viewpager tag in xml

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a simple interface for single tap and for long press events, by passing “view” and its “position” as parameters.

```
public static interface ClickListener{
    public void onClick(View view,int position);
    public void onLongClick(View view,int position);
}
```

Let’s create an inner class implementing RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener. We also need to make use of ClickListener interface in this inner class. GestureDetector class is used to listen for various touch events.

```
class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener{

    private ClickListener clicklistener;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recycleView, final ClickListener clicklistener){

        this.clicklistener=clicklistener;
        gestureDetector=new GestureDetector(context,new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child=recycleView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(),e.getY());
                if(child!=null && clicklistener!=null){
                    clicklistener.onLongClick(child,recycleView.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        View child=rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(),e.getY());
        if(child!=null && clicklistener!=null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)){
            clicklistener.onClick(child,rv.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
}
```

Now let’s add the ItemTouchListener to the RecyclerView, where we will pass RecyclerTouchListener class. This will implement onClick and onLongClick methods.These methods will listen for the click and long press events on the particular position of the view.

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(this,
        recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view, final int position) {
        //Values are passing to activity & to fragment as well
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Single Click on position        :"+position,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Long press on position :"+position,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}));
```

In order to access particular view component inside RecyclerView.We can define the component by findViewById via it’s respective View. Here is the code for you.

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(this,
        recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view, final int position) {
        //Values are passing to activity & to fragment as well
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Single Click on position :"+position,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ImageView picture=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.picture);
        picture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Single Click on Image :"+position,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Long press on position :"+position,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}));
```